# Remove group permissions from list

Tags: list, permissions, groups

I need to remove all the groups with unique permissions from a sharepoint online list, without knowing their names, just removing them all, role inheritance is already broken at this point, what is the fastest way to achieve this?

[image]

Like doing that

EDIT: Via C# CSOM, forgot to specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it myself, code:

```
public void RemovePermissionsFromList(string url, string listName)
    {
        using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Username, Password);

            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
            ctx.Load(list, l => l.RoleAssignments.Include(r => r.Member));
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var group in list.RoleAssignments)
            {
                list.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(group.Member).DeleteObject();
            }

            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```